# Basic linear regression with LINESTX not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, linear-regression

There must be something very basic that I'm missing here...
I tried to add linear regression to some visables using this type of DAX code:

```
BWi (Linear regr.) = 
    VAR Known =
        FILTER (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                ALLSELECTED (PQDateTable[Date]),
                "Known[X]", PQDateTable[Date],
                "Known[Y]", BwiTable[BWi]
            ),
            AND (
                NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[X] ) ),
                NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[Y] ) )
            )
        )
    VAR Line = 
        LINESTX(
            Known,
            Known[Y],
            Known[X]
        )

    // y = kx + m
    VAR k = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Slope", [Slope1])
    VAR m = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Int", [Intercept])
    VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE(PQDateTable[Date])
    VAR y = k*x+m
    RETURN y
```

Now that didn't work and I couldn't figure out why. I thought that maybe it had to do with the initial virtual table "Known" and the measure "BwiTable[BWi]" that I'm using.

I created a small table with just a few values:

BWi-tabell 2023

| Date | BWi |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-08 | 1,59 |
| 2023-01-15 | 1,63 |
| 2023-01-22 | 1,56 |
| 2023-01-31 | 1,50 |
| 2023-02-05 | 1,60 |
| 2023-02-12 | 1,63 |
| 2023-02-19 | 1,51 |
| 2023-02-28 | 1,59 |
| 2023-03-05 | 1,64 |
| 2023-03-12 | 1,59 |
| 2023-03-19 | 1,57 |
| 2023-03-26 | 1,48 |
| 2023-03-31 | 1,52 |
| 2023-04-09 | 1,58 |
| 2023-04-16 | 1,56 |
| 2023-04-23 | 1,53 |
| 2023-04-30 | 1,55 |
| 2023-05-01 | 1,02 |
| 2023-05-07 | 1,64 |
| 2023-05-14 | 1,64 |
| 2023-05-21 | 1,53 |
| 2023-05-28 | 1,56 |
| 2023-05-31 | 1,54 |

Date column of type date and BWi is a number.
So, just by looking at the values you can see that slope should be close to zero(0) and intercept around 1,5.
So I modified my linear regression code to this:

```
Linreg = 
    VAR Line = LINESTX(
        'BWi-data 2023',
        'BWi-data 2023'[BWi],
        'BWi-data 2023'[Date]
    )
    // y = kx + m
    VAR k = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Slope", [Slope1])
    VAR m = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Int", [Intercept])
    VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE('BWi-data 2023'[Date])
    VAR y = k*x+m
    RETURN m
```

Returning the intercept value "m" gives something like 29,12 as a result, when something like 1,5 is expected.
Can anyone please enlighten me and describe what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe because you are using dates, they are being converted to the epoch number, for example the 31st of May will be `45077`

If you apply the kx+m calculation you get for that date:

```
45077*-0.000612530993328773 + 29.1155743306034 = 1.504514744322299479
```

So nothing seems wrong here. Back to your original formula, I believe the issue might be on how you obtain the `Known` table. You can try (not sure which one suits your model best):

```
VAR Known =
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ('BwiTable'),
            AND (
                NOT ( ISBLANK ( BwiTable[Date]) ),
                NOT ( ISBLANK ( BwiTable[BWi] ) )
            )
        )
    VAR Line = 
        LINESTX(
            Known,
            BwiTable[BWi],
            BwiTable[Date]
        )
```

or

```
VAR Known = FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE(
        ALLSELECTED (PQDateTable[Date]),
        PQDateTable[Date],
        "bwi", SUM(BwiTable[BWi])
        ), NOT(ISBLANK([bwi])))
    VAR Line = 
        LINESTX(
            Known,
            [bwi],
            'PQDateTable[Date]
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and suggestion. Then I understand that the k and m values is actually calculated correctly. I also see my mistake not using the ALLSELECTED function. The original DAX code actually seems to work but now there is another issue when using it in a visual, see below.